# Error when using Expresso with Low Variables

Tags: low-variables, expresso

I'm trying to get Expresso working with Low Variables - but it's not playing nicely :(

I get this error from my template when I view the site:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Low_fieldtype_bridge::get_setting() in
>   /xxxxxxx/system/expressionengine/third_party/low_variables/mod.low_variables.php
>   on line 148

What could be causing this?

Comment: What's the template code? There might be a parse/single/pair tag somewhere for a type that doesn't support it...

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with Expresso and Low variables - with any template code e.g. {exp:low_variables:single var="lv_welcome_message" } where 'lv_welcome_message is an expresso item. Can anyone help? Thanks
Martyn

Comment: I ended up not using Expresso, it seemed it wasn't well supported in Low Variables.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Jason. What did you settle on? I am considering 'editor' do you know if that plays ball with Low Variables?

Comment: Support at Low is really fantastic. You should drop him an email.